# Trouble Installing APT on Centos 6 64 bit

Tags: apt, yum, centos

Can someone help me get apt-get installed?

I followed these [instructions](http://dag.wiee.rs/blog/using-apt-in-an-rpm-world) to try and install APT on Centos 6 64 bit:

1. `wget http://pkgs.repoforge.org/rpmforge-release/rpmforge-release-0.5.3-1.el6.rf.x86_64.rpm`
2. `rpm --import http://apt.sw.be/RPM-GPG-KEY.dag.txt`
3. `rpm -K rpmforge-release-0.5.3-1.el6.rf.*.rpm`
4. `rpm -i rpmforge-release-0.5.3-1.el6.rf.*.rpm`
5. **`yum install apt`**

On step 5 I get this output and error:

```
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror, priorities, security
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
 * rpmforge: mirror.team-cymru.org
27 packages excluded due to repository priority protections
Setting up Install Process
No package apt available.
Error: Nothing to do
```

I think I looked at the listing of packages here: http://pkgs.repoforge.org/apt/ and there is no Centos 6 64 bit package. Looking at their [build logs](http://pkgs.repoforge.org/apt/_buildlogs/) it seems there is an error building for Centos 6.

Comment: Dumb question by me, why do you want to install `apt-get` when you already have `yum`? APT is typically the package manager tool used on Debian & Ubuntu based distros, while YUM is used by Red Hat based distros such as Fedora, CentOS , and RHEL.

Comment: I'm trying to install something with these dependencies: apt-get install build-essential libboost-all-dev libcurl4-openssl-dev libdb5.1-dev libdb5.1++-dev git qt-sdk libminiupnpc-dev. I only got yum to install git.

Comment: I'll caution you too that the instructions you're referring to are from 2008. YUM used to be a lacking tool in RH distros, it's on par with APT now, doing something better and a few things either equal or a little behind. But I would stick with the default package manager for a given distro, esp. if you're a noob.

Comment: That's the biggest problem, installing `apt` on RH distros does not allow you to now follow directions as described on sites using the APT steps, you're still bound to installing the packages by name as they would show up for the YUM directions.

Comment: @DavidSilvaSmith what is your real goal here? APT is a "means to an end", not really an end itself. Maybe you're asking the wrong question. If the only reason you're installing APT is to install XYZ, then maybe should be asking how to install XYZ.

Comment: There are no packages by the name build-essential, that's a Debian/Ubuntu name for tools that are unique to those distros. This is what we call an [XY Problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). Let's back up and start w/ what are you really trying to accomplish here? What are you trying to install?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There can often be confusion when you're first starting out with either a Debian based distro such as Debian, Ubuntu, or Linux Mint vs. the Red Hat based distros of Fedora, CentOS or RHEL.

There are 4 pieces of software that are responsible for doing the management of package installation and removal. They are as follows:

*For Debian based distros:*

- dpkg
- APT

*For Red Hat based distros:*

- RPM
- YUM

They all do very similar things for their respective platforms. For starters, `rpm` and `dpkg` do almost identical things. They're the low level tools that actually do the heavy lifting of installing software and tracking where it was installed. For the sake of simplicity I won't discuss them further.

#### APT vs. YUM

These 2 tools do exactly the same things as well. They work at a higher level than `dpkg` or `rpm` by facilitating the identifying of dependencies when you tell them to install package X. They also know how to go about getting the RPMs that a given package is comprised of, knowing what mirrors on the internet to go source these items from.

#### Can't I use APT as a YUM replacement?

You can. But APT isn't some magical translation layer that lets you find directions for installing software as described on some blog post, it's still beholden to installing the RPM packages by the names that they would show up with, in the YUM world.

So I would strongly encourage you to abandon this approach and simply stick with using YUM on Red Hat based distros.

Comment: It sounds like you are saying installing APT won't fix my issue because APT will just be a different tool to install the same packages as YUM on my system? I am trying to install these APT packages: build-essential libboost-all-dev libcurl4-openssl-dev libdb5.1-dev libdb5.1++-dev git qt-sdk libminiupnpc-dev

Comment: @DavidSilvaSmith - that is correct. There is no such package as build-essentials on RH distros, that's a Debian-ism. The names of the other pkgs are likely similar but different too. APT won't "translate" this for you.

Comment: @DavidSilvaSmith - try `yum search boost` to find the names of boost libraries available. I use boost for many apps I dev. it's all there.

Comment: Please, edit your answer. You know what's the difference between `then` and `than`?

Comment: @enedil - better?